# TypeOrm how to get Items with multiple categories (Filter)

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

im trying to use the find options or queryBuilder to get products that have for example
the tag "Environment" and "Art"

how can i achieve that? My many to many relation between items and categories is many to many

```html
    @Property()
    @ManyToMany(
        () => Tag
    )
    @JoinTable({
        name: "Product_Tag",
        joinColumn: {
            name: "products",
            referencedColumnName: "id"
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: "tag_id",
            referencedColumnName: "id"
        }
    })
    tags: Tag[];
```

i want to be able to get the items with tag.name =  "art" and "environment",Or more

The following didn't work for me

```html
 query.where("tags.name IN(:...cat)", { cat: ["Environment", "Art"] })
```

Thanks!